# Spring Boot Application Throwing Startup Failed Error When Trying to Run

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to run a sample Spring Boot Application provided here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I want this to be built as a war, which then should automatically deploy to localhost using tomcat. I've done this once before, but I am unsure as to why it doesn't work now. Here is the error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=62537 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=62538:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Jack\springtomcat\target\classes;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\1.5.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.5.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.5.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.5.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.11\logback-classic-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.11\logback-core-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.25\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.3.5.Final\hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.10\jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.8.0\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.10\jackson-core-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\1.5.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring4\2.1.5.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\2.1.5.RELEASE\thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\3.0.8\ognl-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.21.0-GA\javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.0.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\nz\net\ultraq\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-layout-dialect\1.4.0\thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Jack\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy\2.4.12\groovy-2.4.12.jar" com.test.Server.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.8.RELEASE)

2017-10-18 17:33:07.775  INFO 3076 --- [           main] com.test.Server.Application              : Starting Application on DESKTOP-S193TQ4 with PID 3076 (C:\Users\Jack\springtomcat\target\classes started by Jack in C:\Users\Jack\springtomcat)
2017-10-18 17:33:07.777  INFO 3076 --- [           main] com.test.Server.Application              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-10-18 17:33:07.927  INFO 3076 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4b9e255: startup date [Wed Oct 18 17:33:07 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-18 17:33:07.993  WARN 3076 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.test.Server.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
2017-10-18 17:33:07.998 ERROR 3076 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4b9e255: startup date [Wed Oct 18 17:33:07 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.test.Server.Application.main(Application.java:16) [classes/:na]

2017-10-18 17:33:08.005 ERROR 3076 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.test.Server.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.test.Server.Application.main(Application.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:380) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:314) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code for the simple classes provided by the tutorial:

GreetingController.java

```
package com.test.Components;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import com.test.Models.Greeting;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Greeting.java

```
package com.test.Models;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

I have modified the main class to look like this:

```
package com.test.Server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My project structure looks like this:
[image]

And this is my maven file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>springtomcat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am truly at a loss as to why it does not work. I included the necessary dependencies for building the war and using tomcat, and I do a clean and install for maven each time I run it. My war is CORRECTLY output to the Target folder as well. My configuration simply looks like this:

[image]

I have already tried messing with the package structure and using scanBasePackages, but nothing changes the error.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: This might be a problem with Intellij  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840102/cant-produce-war-file-from-spring-boot-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't produce WAR file from Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840102/cant-produce-war-file-from-spring-boot-application)

Comment: I am NOT having trouble producing a WAR file. The WAR file is output to my target folder. The problem is in Spring itself.

Comment: Once you add the dependency of `spring-boot-starter-web`, your application will automatically be a standalone web application with embedded Tomcat as default web container.

Comment: @LHCHIN removing that didn't fix anything. I'm figuring I'll leave it in there anyways because it helps me remember what dependencies I'm using.

Comment: @everton this looks promising but the steps that are provided in that link do not make any sense to me. There is no "dependencies tab" in the project structure settings. Any help?

Comment: I don't mean to remove this dependency, the correct way is to exclude the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` in `spring-boot-starter-web` if you want to deploy your WAR file to any Servlet 3 container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I do not have a complete solution. I ran into the same problems that @Olantobi pointed out in the comments on my post. Firstly, I needed to add this to my main class Application.java to make it work with my configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.test")
```

An example of what this looks like:

[image]

The other thing I needed to do to get it to run and deploy to localhost is this:

[image]

This works now. I am not sure if I will need to do anything special to get it to run on an AWS elastic beanstalk server, but I might make a comment here if I do need to.

Comment: To those reading: deploying this to AWS Elastic Beanstalk required that I create a application.properties file in the resources folder and set the server.port=5000. This is the default port that AWS will try to run the application on, and the default of 8080 will not work.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is presented here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263216/1937953

TLDR remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from the dependency of `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` in the pom.xml file

Answer (score 4):

i think there is a misunderstanding here, in spring boot we don't need to create a war in order to deploy in tomcat server. The advantage of using spring boot is that it adds all the required dependencies. So you need to just develop the application

Here are the following steps you can try to make it work.

1. if you want your project to create a war file and deploy it in an external server you need to set your scope of the tomcat dependency in spring boot to "provided".

   ```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>`
   ```
2. if you want your application to be deployed automatically after ruuning the spring boot application you set the scope to "compile".

   ```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>`
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Because Spring Boot will automatically add embedded Tomcat dependencies as default choice while you add `spring-boot-starter-web` into your pom file. And you can directly run you application as a standalone web application.

As I said in the comment under your question, you need to exclude the dependency of `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` in `spring-boot-starter-web` if you want to deploy your WAR file to any Servlet 3 container.

Foe example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. What has worked so far is using the command line command for spring boot run, provided within the IDE, IntelliJ. I will post an answer in a second.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by :

1 Edit pom.xml change scope provider -> compile

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provider</scope>
</dependency>
```

2 Right Click Project -> Maven -> Reload Project

3 Run Application

Answer (score 0):

remove scope :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

or replace with compile:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Adding this Resolved my problem**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```